# Can someone help to explain how the lambda expression works in this context?

Tags: java, lambda, vaadin

I'm following a Vaadin/Spring Boot tutorial and they're using lambda functions in a way that I don't really understand. If someone could maybe help explain why they work and what the function is doing? I've tried watching some videos and I'm fairly new to this side of more complex Java programming since I've only been using Java for about a year.

```
private void configureGrid() {
        grid.addClassName("contact-grid");
        grid.setSizeFull();
        grid.setColumns("firstName", "lastName", "email");
        grid.addColumn(contact -> contact.getStatus().getName()).setHeader("Status");
        grid.addColumn(contact -> contact.getCompany().getName()).setHeader("Company");
        grid.getColumns().forEach(col -> col.setAutoWidth(true));


    }
```

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxy2JgqqKDU) is the tutorial I've been following, the programmer starts to implement the lambda functions at around 17 minutes if you need further context.

Comment: What are you having difficulty understanding? It literally does what it says: for each column, do `setAutoWidth(true)` on it.

Comment: Well when I'm adding columns, does doing (contact ->) make refer to each instance of a contact and have it go through that process?

Comment: Yes. `forEach` goes through all of the items returned by `getColumns` and runs the lambda on them.

Comment: @ndc I think the lambdas the OP is having issue with are the ones in `grid.addColumn(...)`, not the `forEach`. Basically, to the uninitiated, it's unclear why a lambda expression can be added as a column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we're talking about this Lambda expression:

```
        grid.addColumn(contact -> contact.getStatus().getName())
```

, it creates a *column definition* for the Grid. By itself, it doesn't do anything yet.

Once you add data into the Grid, this column definition will be used to determine what will be shown in that column.

Each row in the Grid represents an item in the data set. Your example doesn't show the Grid's generic type, but based on the variable naming, I'm going to assume it's something like `Grid<Contact>`. So your `grid` is a component that displays `Contact`s.

Let's look at the lambda expression `contact -> contact.getStatus().getName()`. The lambda expression's left side, `contact` is the input. The right side, `contact.getStatus().getName()` is the output. So putting all this together, for each row in the Grid, we invoke this expression. We're processing the current row's `Contact` data item, and we fetch `.getStatus().getName()` as the value to display for that row, in this current column. So the value to display in the column is the name of the status of the contact. In another column, we display `contact.getCompany().getName()` - the company name of the contact.

Both of the `addColumn(...)` lines end with `.setHeader()` calls - this is a builder which works on the value returned from the previous method call. In those `setHeader()` calls, the header of the column is set.